# javascript dropdown menu onclick

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I've been working at this for a while now, but don't understand what's wrong with my code. I'm sure it's something simple - it always is!

Basically, I have a drop down menu, with some options. I want it to go to a web page when the third option, plumber, is selected. When any of the others are clicked, nothing should happen.

My code so far is:

```
<select id = 'search'>
<option value="1">Carpenter</option>
<option value="2">Electrician</option>
<option value="3">Plumber</option>
<option value="4">Tiler</option>
<option value="5">Boiler Installation</option>

</select>
```

Go

And my javascript is:

```
<script>
function go_button {
if (search.value=="3") {
location="search_results.htm"
}
}

</script>​​​​​​​
```

But it's not working. Could someone tell me what's wrong?

Thanks.

C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either put a [change event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) on your control via script or add it directly to your control..

Direct Method:

```
<select id="search" onChange="OnSelectedIndexChange()">
```

This is the function you need to put in your Script:

```
//function for changed selection
function OnSelectedIndexChange()
{
if (document.getElementById('search').value == "3"){
    location.href="search_results.htm";
}
}
```

Add Change event using Script (either JavaScript or JQuery):

I suggest [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) for doing so (the onSelectedIndexChange function is obsolete here)

```
$('#search').change( function() {

if(this.val() == "3"){
location.href="search_results.htm";
}

});
```

If you don't want to use JQuery just add the following code:

```
    var yourdropdown = document.getElementById('search');
    yourdropdown.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return OnSelectedIndexChange();")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell javascript which element it is you are interested in.

Use `getElementById("search")` to return the element then you can look into getting its value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="search">
```

I think, there are to many spaces.

```
getElementById("search").value
```

I have not used this in a while, but is not it ...

```
location.href = "search_results.htm";
```

Somewhat like this gives you access to the object. And last but not least, you need to associate your function "go_button" with an event of the drop down box, something like this:

```
<select id="search" onClick="go_button();">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think - if possible - use jQuery or other js framework, both have built-in select and other html/dom plugins & methods.